# How to solve problems with tensorflow to see if use gpu?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I don't know which versions are compatible with tensorflow and tensorflow-gpu ver 2.4.1 with grpcio... What should I do?

```
Collecting grpcio
  Using cached grpcio-1.60.1-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl (3.7 MB)
Installing collected packages: grpcio
  Attempting uninstall: grpcio
    Found existing installation: grpcio 1.32.0
    Uninstalling grpcio-1.32.0:
      Successfully uninstalled grpcio-1.32.0
Successfully installed grpcio-1.60.1
ERROR: tensorflow 2.4.1 has requirement grpcio~=1.32.0, but you'll have grpcio 1.60.1 which is incompatible.
ERROR: tensorflow-gpu 2.4.1 has requirement grpcio~=1.32.0, but you'll have grpcio 1.60.1 which is incompatible.
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:
`conda install cudnn`

Then, test if tensorflow recognizes your gpu:

`import tensorflow as tf`

`tf.config.list_physical_devices()`